# Ajax getting cancelled in browser

Tags: php, ajax

When I click and run my ajax script, I see this error in Chrome:

```
Status: cancelled
```

The json data returns to the page in the url bar. My sql table is updating but the error message I indicate above is displaying and the modal doesn't remain open. I suspect there could be a few problems here but I wonder if anybody notice something.

This ajax script is inside a PHP variable that is why you may see some escaped characters. Here the `$row` is a PHP array. Please don't get confused.

```
 $("document").ready(function() {
 $(".form-inline'.$row["userid"].'").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault;
var formData = new FormData($(".form-inline'.$row["userid"].'")[0]);
console.log();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            url: "sponsorship.php",
            data: formData,
             success: function(response) {
                      if (response.success) {
                        $("#myModal'.$row["userid"].'").modal(\'show\');
                        $(".form-inline'.$row["userid"].'").hide();
                        $("#paypalform'.$row["userid"].'").show();
                        $("#alertmessage'.$row["userid"].'").show();
                        $("#closebutton'.$row["userid"].'").hide();
                        }
                      else {
                          console.log("An error has ocurred: sentence: " + response.sentence + "error: " + response.error);
                      }
                  },
                   contentType: false, 
                   processData: false,
                   error: function() {
                      alert("this error is getting displayed");
                  }
       });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`event.preventDefault` is a function. You're referencing it, but not calling it.

The default action of the submit event will therefore happen, causing you to leave the page and terminate the JS.

Don't forget to put `()` when you are trying to call a function.

Comment: that did it! Nice catch

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with String conctatination on your JS :

```
$("#myModal'.$row["userid"].'").modal(\'show\');
                        $(".form-inline'.$row["userid"].'").hide();
                        $("#paypalform'.$row["userid"].'").show();
                        $("#alertmessage'.$row["userid"].'").show();
                        $("#closebutton'.$row["userid"].'").hide();
```

You have to either fix the concatination :

```
$("#myModal'.$row['userid'].'")
```

Or I'm assuming you are missing the php tags on **$row**

Comment: Yes, he was messing with the php tag `$row`